# How do you overlay text perfectly from a textarea onto div with same text?

Tags: html, css, text, overlay

I'm looking to overlap the same texts right on top of each other for an interesting idea I had on syntax highlighting.

I'm trying to do it with the `textarea` in the foreground, and the `div` in the background.
After setting the same position of the elements as well as the same font size, they still do not overlap perfectly. What am I missing, exactly?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oy0x3wo3/)

```
div,textarea{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
background:transparent;
font-size:1em;
line-height:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set a same `font-family` for both

`textarea` has `1px` border so you can add `border:1px solid transparent` to `div` which has the text so that it aligns

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div{
    border:1px solid transparent
}
div,
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello, world!</div>
<textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
```

Comment: Wow! This is great! Now, would there be a way to make the final result look not so..bold?

Comment: So you just added a border? How exactly does that make it thinner? I'm curious about the logic behind this.

Comment: Haha yes of course. I was waiting for 52 seconds and got engrossed in code again. :P

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `font-family`, `padding`, and `border-width` explicitly:

```
div,textarea{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:transparent;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1em;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    border-width:0;
}
```

Two comments:

1. Browsers define a default style for `textarea` elements, so the trick is to figure out what properties are being set by the browser and override those explicitly. It's best to **override the properties on both the `div` and the `textarea`**. If you only change the `div` to accommodate for the browser's default style of the `textarea`, you'll get varying results in different browsers. For example, in Chrome the default border width for a `textarea` is 1 pixel, while in Firefox, it's 2 pixels.
2. Due to the way font anti-aliasing works, you'll always get a slightly bold effect. Probably best to set one of the two font colors to white or transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/oy0x3wo3/2/)

```
div,textarea{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:transparent;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1em;
    font-family:arial /*add same font-family */
}
```

and

```
 div{
   padding:3px 3px 0
  }
```

Comment: A bit off compared for Vitorino Fernandes's example, but close! I understand the general idea though. I personally wasn't paying attention to all of the box properties, as well as the font.